# glossaries package: disable hyperlink for acronym only

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I'm using `\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}` and am aware of the switch `\glsdisablehyper`, however this affects my glossary entries and acronyms. How could I disable hyperlinks to my acronyms only?

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shown how you currently use the `glossaries-extra` package. Please also clarify "disable hyperlinks to my acronyms". Does this refer to the hyperlink that poonts from an acronym in the text to the corresponding entry in the list of acronyms or something else?

Comment: I don't quite think a MWE is necessary here.. but I can work towards making one. As you pointed out, I am wanting to disable the hyperlink between acronyms as the appear in the main body and jump to the list of acronyms produced with `\printglossary`

Comment: I'm dropping this here in case someone else comes across the same issue as me. If you're using the `acronym` package to generate the glossary, then you can use the `nohyperlinks` option. It suppresses the generation of hyperlinks for acronyms. `\usepackage[nohyperlinks]{acronym}`

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but if you use the `shortcuts` option, you can use `\ac` instead of `\gls` for your acronyms and keep `\gls` for the glossary entries. Both commands offer the starred variant, which suppresses hyperlinks, so a combination of `\gls` and `\ac*` should give you the expected result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample1}{name={sample1},description={an example}}
\newglossaryentry{sample2}{name={sample2},description={another example}}

\newacronym{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}
\newacronym{tug}{TUG}{\TeX\ User Group}

\begin{document}
\ac*{html} and \ac*{tug}. 

\gls{sample1} and  \gls{sample2}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. At this point, my document is a 100 pages long and I've committed to using `\gls{}` for all my entries.